# Attack on Androids Encryption called FROST

Tags: encryption, attacks, android

http://www.extremetech.com/computing/150536-how-to-bypass-an-android-smartphones-encryption-and-security-put-it-in-the-freezer

I read this article about FROST and in the comments someone was stating that this process would not work with new androids with built in batteries.

I can not believe this is true because if a device gets bricked within the warranty time some technician will have to repair it and will open it up so i guess this attack wil still work with the new android devices, what are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what quote you are referring to in the article but I can answer in generally.

You certainly could pop the case to remove the battery so phones with fixed batteries don't seem much safer than phones with removable batteries.

But a bricked phone is probably safe from the warranty techs. The attack only works if you chill the phone while it is turned on has the decryption key in RAM. It seems hard to imagine that you'll brick your phone, after having entered the decryption key, with RAM still powered up, and get it to techs before the battery runs out. I wouldn't say it's impossible, but not very likely.